# Unix count lines starting with same number

Tags: unix

i have a text corpus and already sorted it by frequency:

```
tr ' ' '\n' < corpus.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Now i want to count up all lines that start with the same number.

For example:

```
100 the
50 in
50 and
10 cat
10 dog
```

should return:

```
100 1
50 2
10 2
```

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Easy with `awk`:

```
$ awk '{count[$1]++} END {for (i in count) print i, count[i]}' file
100 1
10 2
50 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tweak your already written command:-

```
cut -d' ' -f1 corpus.txt| sort -rn | uniq -c
```

Required output is:-

```
1 100
2 50
2 10
```